# Sort products by brand and title in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, product

In Woocommerce I'm currently trying to change the default `orderby` in to show products sorted by their brand and title.

The brands are done via perfect Woocommerce brands. I've managed to get the ordering according to the brand slug (as that is how I set their order).
I'm also using WOOF (Woocommerce products filter) plugin to filter by category/brand.

I'm sorting products by the taxonomy **`wpb-brand`** and I'm looking for a way to secondary sort by product title but I'm not aware of how I can do this.

This is my code:

```
add_filter('posts_clauses', 'posts_clauses_with_tax', 10, 2);
function posts_clauses_with_tax( $clauses, $wp_query ) {
global $wpdb;

$taxonomies = array('pwb-brand');

$orderBy['field'] = "pwb-brand";
$orderBy['direction'] = "ASC";

if( in_array($orderBy['field'], $taxonomies) ) {
    $clauses['join'] .= "
        LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS rel2 ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = rel2.object_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} AS tax2 ON rel2.term_taxonomy_id = tax2.term_taxonomy_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} USING (term_id)
    ";

    $clauses['where'] .= " AND (taxonomy = '".$orderBy['field']."' OR taxonomy IS NULL)";
    $clauses['groupby'] = "rel2.object_id";
    $clauses['orderby']  = "GROUP_CONCAT({$wpdb->terms}.slug ORDER BY slug ASC) ";
    $clauses['orderby'] .= ( 'ASC' == strtoupper( $orderBy['direction'] ) ) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
    return $clauses;
}
else {
    return $clauses;
}
}
```

Is there any way I could get the products object to add a second **`orderby`** clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to solve the issue.

It was as simple as commenting out the last 'orderby' line as it was somewhat redundant and get the posts table via the database object.

```
//$clauses['orderby'] .= ( 'ASC' == strtoupper( $orderBy['direction'] ) ) ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';
$clauses['orderby'] .= ", {$wpdb->posts}.post_title ASC";
```

Comment: I added 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'add_brand_sorting_option');
 
function add_brand_sorting_option( $options ){
 
 $options['pwb-brand'] = 'Sort by brand';
 
 return $options;
 
}

Comment: @TejasPatel That doesn't actually sort the products. It just adds 'Sort by brand' option in the Customize view only