# Sort products by brand and price in Woocommerce

Tags: php, sorting, woocommerce, product, price

While trying to reproduce the solution found here ([Sort products by brand and title in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866908/sort-products-by-brand-and-title-in-woocommerce)) by modifying it, I came across a bone ...

The first sort by brand works like a charm however I cannot find a way to do a second sort by increasing or decreasing price.

```
add_filter('posts_clauses', 'posts_clauses_with_tax', 10, 2);
function posts_clauses_with_tax( $clauses, $wp_query ) {
global $wpdb;

$taxonomies = array('pwb-brand');

$orderBy['field'] = "pwb-brand";
$orderBy['direction'] = "ASC";

if( in_array($orderBy['field'], $taxonomies) ) {
    $clauses['join'] .= "
        LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS rel2 ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = rel2.object_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} AS tax2 ON rel2.term_taxonomy_id = tax2.term_taxonomy_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} USING (term_id)
    ";

    $clauses['where'] .= " AND (taxonomy = '".$orderBy['field']."' OR taxonomy IS NULL)";
    $clauses['groupby'] = "rel2.object_id";
    $clauses['orderby']  = "GROUP_CONCAT({$wpdb->terms}.slug ORDER BY slug ASC) ";
    $clauses['orderby'] .= ", {$wpdb->posts}.post_title ASC";
    return $clauses;
}
else {
    return $clauses;
}
}
```

I've found those lines but it's very hard for me to add those lines in the query above to replace the orderby title by price ASC

```
$clauses['join'] .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} price ON( {$wpdb->posts }.ID = price.post_id AND price.meta_key = 'price') ";
$clauses['orderby'] = " CONVERT( REPLACE(price.meta_value, '$', ''), DECIMAL(13,2) ) " . $order;
```

Do you have any idea of the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's always when we write the question and develop that the answer comes later ...

Here is the complete solution to add a custom filter brand and price ASC in your WooCommerce by using the plugin [Perfect Brands for WooCommerce](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/perfect-woocommerce-brands/)

First, add the custom filter :

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'my_add_custom_sorting_options' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options',  'my_add_custom_sorting_options' );
function my_add_custom_sorting_options( $options ){
    $options['brands'] = __("Tri par marque / prix croissant", "yourdomain");
    return $options;
}
```

And than add

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    if ( 'brands' == $orderby_value ) {
        add_filter('posts_clauses', 'posts_clauses_brands_price', 10, 2);
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Finally

```
function posts_clauses_brands_price( $clauses, $wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb;
        
    $taxonomies = array('pwb-brand');
        
    $orderBy['field'] = "pwb-brand";
    $orderBy['direction'] = "ASC";
        
    if( in_array($orderBy['field'], $taxonomies) ) {
        $clauses['join'] .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->wc_product_meta_lookup} wc_product_meta_lookup ON $wpdb->posts.ID = wc_product_meta_lookup.product_id ";
        $clauses['join'] .= "
            LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS rel2 ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = rel2.object_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} AS tax2 ON rel2.term_taxonomy_id = tax2.term_taxonomy_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} USING (term_id)
        ";
            
        $clauses['where'] .= " AND (taxonomy = '".$orderBy['field']."' OR taxonomy IS NULL)";
        $clauses['groupby'] = "rel2.object_id";
        $clauses['orderby'] = "GROUP_CONCAT({$wpdb->terms}.slug ORDER BY slug ASC) ";
        $clauses['orderby'] .= ', wc_product_meta_lookup.min_price ASC, wc_product_meta_lookup.product_id ASC ';

        return $clauses;
    }
    else {
        return $clauses;
    }
}
```