# My "WooCommerce product custom sorting function" crashes post/pages in Wordpress Dashbord

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, product

I needed a function that could sort WooCommerce products by brand.

I found one here:
[Sort products by brand and title in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53866908/sort-products-by-brand-and-title-in-woocommerce).

So basically this is the code that I put in my child themes "function.php":

```
add_filter('posts_clauses', 'posts_clauses_with_tax', 10, 2);
function posts_clauses_with_tax( $clauses, $wp_query ) {

    global $wpdb;
    $taxonomies = array('pwb-brand');
    $orderBy['field'] = "pwb-brand";
    $orderBy['direction'] = "ASC";

    if( in_array($orderBy['field'], $taxonomies) ) {
        $clauses['join'] .= "
            LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS rel2 ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = rel2.object_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} AS tax2 ON rel2.term_taxonomy_id = tax2.term_taxonomy_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} USING (term_id)
        ";
        
        $clauses['where'] .= " AND (taxonomy = '".$orderBy['field']."' OR taxonomy IS NULL)";
        $clauses['groupby'] = "rel2.object_id";
        $clauses['orderby']  = "GROUP_CONCAT({$wpdb->terms}.slug ORDER BY slug ASC) ";
      
        $clauses['orderby'] .= ", {$wpdb->posts}.post_title ASC"; 
        return $clauses;
    }
    else {
        return $clauses;
    }  
}//End function
```

This code works perfect when it comes to sorting the products, but the big problem is that it kind of crashes the display of posts and pages in Dashbord. Both posts and pages are missing. Then it becomes real hard to editing a post/page. The post/pages are actually not removed because if I comment out the sorting code from function.php then all the posts and pages are again displayed in the Dashbord.

So when enabling the sorting code in function.php something in Wordpress breaks.
Is there any tweak that can be done in the code to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

By hooking the function to [`post_clauses`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_clauses/) it gets executed everywhere in WordPress (front and back-end). The code needs to be tweaked, so it executes only on the product listing page in the admin. In your case the edit.php (`$pagenow`, listing page) for products (`$typenow`).

I've modified it. Notice the early returns.

```php
add_filter('posts_clauses', 'posts_clauses_with_tax', 10, 2);
function posts_clauses_with_tax( $clauses, $wp_query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        return $clauses;
    }

    global $pagenow;
    if ( $pagenow !== 'edit.php' ) {
        return $clauses;
    }

    global $typenow;
    if ( $typenow !== 'product' ) {
        return $clauses;
    }

    global $wpdb;
    $taxonomies = array('pwb-brand');
    $orderBy['field'] = "pwb-brand";
    $orderBy['direction'] = "ASC";

    if( in_array($orderBy['field'], $taxonomies) ) {
        $clauses['join'] .= "
        LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS rel2 ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = rel2.object_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} AS tax2 ON rel2.term_taxonomy_id = tax2.term_taxonomy_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN {$wpdb->terms} USING (term_id)
        ";

        $clauses['where'] .= " AND (taxonomy = '".$orderBy['field']."' OR taxonomy IS NULL)";
        $clauses['groupby'] = "rel2.object_id";
        $clauses['orderby']  = "GROUP_CONCAT({$wpdb->terms}.slug ORDER BY slug ASC) ";

        $clauses['orderby'] .= ", {$wpdb->posts}.post_title ASC"; 
        return $clauses;
    } else {
        return $clauses;
    }
}//End function
```